# KnockoutJS data-bind optionsCaption

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

```js
var vm = {
  WeatherId: ko.observable(),
  WeatherConditions: [{
    Id: '1',
    Name: 'Sunny'
  }, {
    Id: '2',
    Name: 'Rainy'
  }, {
    Id: '3',
    Name: 'Cloudy'
  }, {
    Id: '4',
    Name: 'Snowy'
  }]
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: WeatherConditions,   
value: WeatherId, 
optionsText:'Name',
optionsCaption: 'Select today weather'">
</select>
```

I have this KO data bind snippet where I want to set  `optionsCaption` to read as "Select today's weather". I wasn't able to inset the apostrophe in the middle - need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the apostrophe with backslash `\`

`optionsCaption: 'Select today\'s weather'">`

```js
var vm = {
  WeatherId: ko.observable(),
  WeatherConditions: [{
    Id: '1',
    Name: 'Sunny'
  }, {
    Id: '2',
    Name: 'Rainy'
  }, {
    Id: '3',
    Name: 'Cloudy'
  }, {
    Id: '4',
    Name: 'Snowy'
  }]
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: WeatherConditions,   
value: WeatherId, 
optionsText:'Name',
optionsCaption: 'Select today\'s weather'">
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks @agalo .. this works - my original problem was actually unrelated and thought it was this piece causing the issue - 'm all good now.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to escape the `'`:  `today\'s`:

```js
var vm = {
  WeatherId: ko.observable(),
  WeatherConditions: [{
    Id: '1',
    Name: 'Sunny'
  }, {
    Id: '2',
    Name: 'Rainy'
  }, {
    Id: '3',
    Name: 'Cloudy'
  }, {
    Id: '4',
    Name: 'Snowy'
  }]
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: WeatherConditions,   
value: WeatherId, 
optionsText:'Name',
optionsCaption: 'Select today\'s weather'">
</select>
```

This isn't a KnockoutJS thing, it's a basic JavaScript thing. To put a `'` in a `'`-quoted string, you use an escape: `today\'s`.

Remember, the content of the `data-bind` attribute is an JavaScript object initializer without the `{` and `}`, whose contents are evaluated within a series of `with` blocks to provide context. (Literally. Knockout builds the text of a function to do that, using as many `with` blocks as it needs for the nesting level, and with a `return {" + theDataBindAttributeText};` at the end, then uses `new Function` to build a function from that, and calls it to get the bindings.)